# Brouwer's fixed point theorem implies Sperner's lemma

Tags: proof-writing, fixed-point-theorems, discrete-geometry

I'm looking for a proof that Brouwer's fixed point theorem implies Sperner's lemma. The proof should be understandable by an undergraduate.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For reverse direction, see Proofs in the Book pg ~148.

Comment: I know, this is an old post, but just for future visitors: I believe Yoseloff (https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82196989.pdf) was the first who published a proof of Sperner's Lemma from **BFPT**.

Answer (score 2):

A simple proof can be found in a paper by Park and Jeong:
A PROOF OF THE SPERNER LEMMA FROM THE BROUWER FIXED POINT THEOREM
Nonlinear Analysis Forum 8(1), pp. 65–67, 2003 (available from http://www.na-forum.org/)