# Deducing Sperner's Lemma from Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem

Tags: combinatorics, general-topology, fixed-point-theorems

A well-known proof of Brouwer's fixed point theorem utilizes Sperner's Lemma. Can we go the other way round--find a simple proof of Sperner's lemma using the fixed point theorem?

Based on a search in google, there are some papers that demonstrate this; but they (as far as I've seen) all go through some intermediate lemma and the proofs are not very simple. I am looking for a simple proof.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Brouwer's fixed point theorem implies Sperner's lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179827/brouwers-fixed-point-theorem-implies-sperners-lemma)